# php - check if directory is a file

Tags: php, directory

I have a directory and I need to list all files inside that. I used this code to output all files:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/'
if(is_dir($path))
    {
        $dh = opendir($path);
        if($dh)
        {
            while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {
                echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
```

This works correct, but always output `.` and `..` at the beginning. Is there anyway to check whether a directory is a file before output it?

Comment: `is_dir()` will tell you whether the filename passed in is a file or directory

Comment: i think, only so `if ($file != "." && $file != "..")`

Comment: `.` and `..` are directories... `.` is the actual directory and `..` is the parent directory

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstand you correctly you are searching for the function `is_dir(filename)`. It returns whether the given filename is a directory or not. For more information see [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).